# iPhone browsing shortcut control in Address book and Music (iPod)

Tags: ios

What's the name of the right hand side control with the initial characters so that you can jump fast to different contacts/artists?
I'm thinking of implementing this thing. Can it be done or do I have to roll something on my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount property on the UITableView class.

Comment: Thx. Needed `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` and some other stuff too.